# Transposing a matrix in python

Tags: python, matrix

I am trying to use nested list comprehension to transpose a matrix in python

I am confused as to why this won't return a transposed matrix. I am trying to implement a matrix transpose in python, specifically using nested list comprehension.

```
return [[row[i] for i in range(len(m))] for row in m]
```

m is my matrix above.

```
m = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

I get back the same matrix I passed in for the return statement above. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear why do you expect that your code can trapspose matrix. So I can't explain what is wrong here. You just copy the matrix instead of transposing. Try this:

```
m = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
print [[row[i] for row in m] for i in range(len(m[0]))]
```

Comment: I see my mistake now. I had the nested for loops mixed up. Thanks